# Overriding the bootstrap class properties

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

**myClass:**

```
 .myfooter{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-top: none;
     border-bottom-right-radius:none; <!--In chrome show inavalid property why?
    border-bottom-left-radius: none;<!--In chrome show inavalid property why?

     }
```

**bootstrap 3:**

```
 .panel-footer {
 padding: 10px 15px;
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
 border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;} <!--copy and paste it here from chrome 
  browser-->
```

**main page:**

```
  <div class="container doc-container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
           <div class="panel-footer myfooter clearfix">
                               <strong>Terms and Conditions:</strong><br>
                                1- Line 1
                                2- Line 2

                            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

I am making an custom class for bootstrap 3 panel. I need to overide all of the properties of `myfooter` with bootstrap `panel-footer`. I properly declared my custom class after bootstrap class in `<header>`. **Now My question is:**

- I need this `.myfooter` class to be only loaded for single page and
  bootstrap class `.panel-footer`for other pages.So how should write
  CSS class for this task?
- Is it bad practice to pick all bootstrap class properties and declared the properties with your need value and declared other
  properties none.That's what i did in my custom class `.myfooter`.

Comment: Can you show me your html

Comment: it is very long.

Comment: just header then

Comment: @SuryaNeupane see the edit. I edit the question.

Comment: I mean your header tag

Comment: i think you are looking for declaring the classes. i correctly placed the `<link>` of both classes. i dont think so there is a problem in header.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you want to use `.myfooter` on one page only, I would personally call that class on that page like `<div class="myfooter"></div>` and on all other pages use `<div class="panel-footer"></div>`

As for picking bootstrap class elements, you could just use two classes `.panel-footer` which has all the standard bootstrap elements, then create a 2nd class to add / change elements to your footer. So could work something like `<div class="panel-footer custom-footer"></div>` and the customer footer would hold your bespoke elements.

Comment: Bro i did what you said. my webapp renderd the bootstrap class properties that i don't need.

Comment: oh! In that I would maybe download the bootstrap css file find what you dont need and delete it. Then move what you do need to your main css file. I have done this a few times before and it's worked fine.

copy what you need to your main css and then delete what you dont need from the bootstrap file. Taking into consideration all margin / padding etc.

Comment: i think it is not good idea. because what i don't need for this page will be needed for other pages.

Comment: you would create the classes and just call them when you need them?